# Echo durations from multiple dates (ex. Aug 25-27, Sep 3)

Tags: php, date, formatting, date-range

I'm dealing with events that can either take place on a single day (ex. 5/20) or multiple days (ex. 8/25, 8/26, 8/27, 9/3).

Given, for example, a 4-day event taking place on 8/25, 8/26, 8/27, and 9/3, I'd like to echo this:

```
Aug 25-27, Sep 3
```

I'd like the code to:

- Handle single day events (ex. Oct 3)
- Group consecutive days (ex. Jan 25-27)
- Separate non-consecutive days with a comma (ex. Sep 19, 22)
- Handle a range of dates spanning multiple months (ex. Feb 28-Mar 2)
- Handle multiple ranges if necessary (ex. Apr 2-4, Jun 10-13)
- Avoid redundant date info (ex. Dec 1-3, *Dec* 8)

This is easy to do with only a single-day event using `date()` formatting, but is it possible to intelligently produce formatting like this using multiple dates when necessary?

Comment: Very likely it is doable. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried experimenting with new DatePeriod, but I'm out of my depth there and I don't think that will allow me to neatly echo dates , but rather to iterate through them.

Comment: Rough idea; strip the `and`, parse the input as CSV, iterate over input (sort first if it won't always be in order), compare current iteration to previous and next, if is next value skip, if not output it with appropriate markings (`-`, `,` or nothing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a function that should output the required string based on an array of `DateTime` objects. I placed some inline comments to indicate what is happening at a given time in the function.

```php
function produceDateString(array $dates): string
{
    // sort the dates
    sort($dates);

    // create an array of arrays that contain ranges of consecutive days
    $ranges = [];
    $currentRange = [];
    foreach ($dates as $date) {
        if(empty($currentRange) || consecutive(end($currentRange), $date)) {
            $currentRange[] = $date;
        } else {
            $ranges[] = $currentRange;
            $currentRange = [$date];
        }
    }
    $ranges[] = $currentRange;

    // create the output string
    $output = '';
    $previous = null;
    foreach ($ranges as $range) {
        // add a comma between each range
        if (!empty($output)) {
            $output .= ', ';
        }

        // the long format should be used on the first occurrence of the loop
        // or when the month of first date in the range doesn't match 
        // the month of the last date in the previous range
        $format = $previous === null || end($previous)->format('m') !== reset($range)->format('m')
            ? 'M. j'
            : 'j';

        // the output differes when there are 1 or multiple dates in a range
        if (count($range) > 1) {
            // the output differs when the end and start are in the sane month
            $output .= sameMonth(reset($range), end($range))
                ? reset($range)->format($format).'-'.end($range)->format('j')
                : reset($range)->format('M. j').'-'.end($range)->format('M. j');
        } else {
            $output .= reset($range)->format($format);
        }

        $previous = $range;
    }

    return $output;
}

function consecutive(DateTime $t1, DateTime $t2): bool
{
    $t1->setTime(0, 0, 0, 0);
    $t2->setTime(0, 0, 0, 0);
    return(abs($t2->getTimestamp() - $t1->getTimestamp()) < 87000);
}

function sameMonth(DateTime $t1, DateTime $t2): bool
{
    return $t1->format('Y-m') === $t2->format('Y-m');
}
```

I made a small [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/8CDjX) to show you how it works exactly. Don't hesitate to ask if you might have any questions about how this works.

Comment: Wow. Very cool code. Much appreciated!

Comment: Bonus question: How would you extend this slightly to also accommodate same YEAR if formatting as (F j, Y)?

Comment: I'd implement a function similar to `sameMonth`, named `sameYear` and perform a nested ternary operation when appending to the output parameter that changes the output to `M. j Y` in case the year is not the same.